# Perl hash to sort key and values

Tags: perl, hash

Below current script is able to sort out hash key and values correctly. Wanted extend the code to check and sort one additional dir/folder in fruit path, then sort of the order as expected output below, without adding the additional layer to the input file. Would like to maintain the hash usage.

Every Fruit path will have one region folder inside for example:

```
/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/asia
/path/userf/some_unique_name/runs/orange/europe
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/berry/afrika
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/melon/afrika
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/apple/europe
/path/userc/some_unique_name/runs/apple/asia
/path/userc/some_unique_name/runs/melon/asia
/path/userd/some_unique_name/runs/melon/afrika
/path/usere/some_unique_name/runs/berry/europe
```

Expected output (sorted according to region name, then sorted according to fruit name):

```
Region: arfika
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/berry/
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/melon/
/path/userd/some_unique_name/runs/melon/

Region : asia
/path/userc/some_unique_name/runs/apple/
/path/userc/some_unique_name/runs/melon/
/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/

Region : europe
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/apple/
/path/usere/some_unique_name/runs/berry/
/path/userf/some_unique_name/runs/orange/
```

Original input File content:

```
/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/
/path/userf/some_unique_name/runs/orange/
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/berry/
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/melon/
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/apple/
/path/userc/some_unique_name/runs/apple/
/path/userc/some_unique_name/runs/melon/
/path/userd/some_unique_name/runs/melon/
/path/usere/some_unique_name/runs/berry/
```

Current Script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "/path/to/file.txt";
my %hash;
   open FILE, "$file" or die $!;
    my $key;
    my $values;
    while (my $line = <FILE>) {
      chomp($line);
      $values = $line;
      ($key) = $values =~ m{/runs/([^/]*)};
      push (@{$hash{$key}}, $values);
    }
    close FILE;

  foreach my $k (sort (keys %hash)){
       print "fruit: $k\n";
    foreach my $path (values @{$hash{$k}}){
    print "$path\n";
}
}
```

Current result:

```
fruit: apple
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/apple/
/path/userc/some_unique_name/runs/apple/
fruit: berry
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/berry/
/path/usere/some_unique_name/runs/berry/
fruit: melon
/path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/melon/
/path/userc/some_unique_name/runs/melon/
/path/userd/some_unique_name/runs/melon/
fruit: orange
/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/
/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/
```

Comment: @ikegami, ya the third is the input, the first is the additional one directory for each fruit path. Every fruit path comes with some number after fruit/

Comment: @ikegami, imagine the numbers to be subdir in each path eg: /path/userb/some_unique_name/runs/apple/dir1 , let me edit the ques

Comment: @ikegami, my mistake when editing, ya "Every Fruit path will have one region folder inside". The path before "runs" is unique. I am trying to use easier example for illustration

Comment: I am now confused -- if the third set of lines (`/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/`), under "_Original input File content:_", is the actual input file then where do the regions come from?  Are such files in directories shown in the first set (`/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/asia`)?  I am not sure I see how this makes sense? (Inside a folder `orange/asia` is a file with paths with `apple` and `berry` etc?) Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First group the paths by region (which requires getting the region), then sort and print the groups.

```perl
use File::Basename qw( basename );
use Sort::Key      qw( keysort );

chomp( my @dir_qfns = <> };

my %by_region;
for my $dir_qfn ( @dir_qfns ) {
   my @regions =
      map { basename( $_ ) }
         glob( "\Q$dir_qfn\E/*" );

   for my $region ( @regions ) {
      push @{ $by_region->{ $region } }, $dir_qfn;
   }
}

for my $region ( sort keys( %by_region ) ) {
   say "Region: $region";

   for my $dir_qfn (
      keysort { basename( $_ ) }
         @{ $by_region->{ $region } }
   ) {
      say $dir_qfn;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The description is a little unclear to me but I take it that you have a file like the first shown set of lines and want to sort it like what is shown next.

One way

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
#use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my %fruit; 

while (<>) { 
    my ($path, $reg) = m{(.+/)(.+)};  #/
    push @{$fruit{$reg}}, $path;
}

for my $reg (sort keys %fruit) {
    say "Region: $reg";
    say for                                 # print for each
        map  { $_->[1] }                    # retrieve path again
        sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }        # sort [...] list by fruit
        map  { [ ( m{.+/(.+)} )[0], $_ ] }  # build [ fruit, path ]
            @{$fruit{$reg}};                  # list of paths
}

#dd \%fruit;   # just to see the data structure
```

The loop with the ["diamond" operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) `while (<>)` reads line by line the files with names given on command line, so run this as `program.pl file1 file2...`

In the loop we build the hash *n => [ paths-for-that-number ]* (path without the number). Then that is printed [sorted](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) as wanted, using [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). (I call the hash `%fruit` for not knowing a suitable name for your problem.)

---

As for the sorting, the extremely useful [Sort::Key](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key) reduces that Schwartzian transform work to one short statement

```
use Sort::Key qw(keysort);

for my $reg (sort keys %fruit) { 
    say "Region: $reg";
    say for keysort { ( m{.+/([^/]+)} )[0] } @{$fruit{$reg}};
}
```

The module is much recommended as it comes with a long list of very useful routines.  See how that `keysort` sub simply takes what to sort on and then takes care of the rest of ST machinery (build the criterion to sort on -- here a regex extraction of the substring -- but in the end show the original strings that are sorted by that criterion).

Thanks to ikegami for the reminder

Comment: Tip: With Sort::Key, you can simplify the map+sort+map down to `keysort { m{.+/(.+)} )[0] }`

Comment: @ikegami Hah, right ... will add that (have to go now).  thank you

Comment: @zdim, the first shown is only to show there will be 1 folder/dir in fruit path, the third is the input

Comment: @walker "_the first shown is only to show there will be 1 folder/dir in fruit path, the third is the input_"  -- thanks for comment. I don't get that, can you explain?  The third shown set of lines has things like  `/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/` -- if that is the input file then there is no region mentioned there at all?  (Why would that go under `afrika` or...?)

Comment: @walker  Btw, I edited -- added to the end an easier way to sort

Comment: @walker  um ... are you saying that there are _folders_ like `/path/usera/some_unique_name/runs/orange/asia` (shown in the first set of lines) and in each folder there is a file (one file?), like the third shown set of lines?  (So path _without_ the region.)